# Sinalização rejeitada com justificativa insuficiente

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, sinalização

Em meio as análises de hoje apareceu [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31940/erro-de-javascript-uncaught-typeerror-n%C3%A3o-consigo-resolver/31961#31961) a qual não estava errada e, por isso, não justificaria recomendar sua exclusão.

No entanto, achei válido sinalizá-la para que alguém com bases mais sólidas que as minhas determinasse se o que eu tinha em mente era válido ou não, isto é, quanto resposta ser um comentário da publicação original.

Porém, o retorno da sinalização foi, numa tradução livre, de que o moderador que analisou a sinalização não encontrou evidências suficientes para caracterizar a sinalização como válida.

Bom, não estou questionando a decisão de rejeitar a sinalização mas, será que não foi uma rejeição incorreta? Do meu ponto de vista a resposta é sim comentário porque a solução encontrada pelo autor do tópico não transparece certeza.

Ele simplesmente chutou e marcou o gol sem querer, tanto é que ele mesmo complementa não saber se é certo ou não.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, Bruno. Fui eu quem rejeitou a flag.

Após ler o histórico de comentários, notei que o pnet havia postado um comentário com a solução.

Vinte minutos depois, o bfavaretto comentou explicando o motivo da solução ter funcionado e o motivo do código original estar com erro.

Duas horas depois o pnet então colocou o comentário como resposta, visto que todo o mistério estava solucionado.

Embora a reposta estivesse sem as informações completas e sem formatação, julguei que deveria rejeitar a flag "não é uma resposta" porque aquela era efetivamente a resposta para o OP.

O que fiz foi melhorá-la um pouco e depois o bfavaretto adicionou um comentário explicativo mais elaborado.

Entretanto, concordo que a flag foi útil, embora talvez a flag mais adequada neste caso em específico seria "baixa qualidade". Bem, é minha opinião num caso que considero limítrofe.

Se pudesse voltar atrás provavelmente teria marcado a flag como *helful*. Sorry :(

Enfim, espero que não fique chateado e continue "flagando" conteúdos que, de uma forma ou de outra, são duvidosos, pois é algo muito útil e importante para a comunidade.

Comment: Sem problemas, só fiquei curioso por saber o porquê da rejeição. Seria bom se existisse a opção de "baixa qualidade" também no box de sinalização.

Answer (score 2):

É uma resposta pobre em explicações, mas só precisava de uma edição para convertê-la de quase-comentário a resposta-mais-ou-menos:

> [image: histórico de edições]

Acho importante destacar na resposta original *"coloquei [...] e funcionou"*, se seria o correto ou não é a parte "comentário" que o utluiz habilmente reverteu. E com um pouco de formatação, já fica com cara de resposta.

Comment: Moral da história: mais vale o coração da resposta que somente a cara.